# Swift - Parse Query whereKey contains

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a parse object that i have saved to the LDS and i want to search for it via 1 key and an entry under another key.

Key: This is fine.

```
checkQuery.whereKeyExists("File-rZVgZNpNuB")
```

Key that contains: This does not work.

```
checkQuery.whereKey("seachKey", contains: "myItem0000000000")
```

The console is printing:

```
 -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c09bbb0
```

I'm guessing because the mySearchString is an object within the "searchKey" field which returns an NSMutable Array.  its easy enough to get the data out of the array once i have the object but i need to search for this string in the "searchKey" field to find the object.  For various reasons i can not just save the object with a key of "myItem0000000000".  perhaps i could add it as a third key when i save the object but that seems a bit messy.

It is there, if i look at the object through SQL Lite i can see it.

```
{"className":"downloadedAudio","__complete":true,"__operations":[{"ACL":{"*":{"read":true},"rZVgZNpNuB":{"write":true,"read":true}},"File-rZVgZNpNuB":{"__op":"Add","objects":[{"url":"https:\/\/parse-server-nextbreath-s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com\/b5d2110dce0b50dc3a1c620731fad66e_The%20Name%20of%20the%20Wind%2024-92.mp3","name":"b5d2110dce0b50dc3a1c620731fad66e_The Name of the Wind 24-92.mp3","__type":"File"}]},"__uuid":"77AE38AF-1ADB-4795-9BB0-5A5AB7205E28","__updatedAt":{"iso":"2017-03-03T21:28:19.637Z","__type":"Date"},"searchKey":{"__op":"Add","objects":["myItem0000000000"]}}],"isDeletingEventually":0}
```

---- EDIT ----
 searching:

```
        let searchKey = "File-\(PFUser.current()!.objectId!)"
        let checkQuery = PFQuery(className: "downloadedAudio")
        checkQuery.whereKeyExists(searchKey)
        //checkQuery.whereKeyExists(item.name)
        //checkQuery.whereKey("seachKey", contains: item.name)
        checkQuery.fromLocalDatastore()
        checkQuery.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
            if object != nil {
                // object?.unpinInBackground()
                object?.unpinInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                    if success {
```

saving:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Part")
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: selectedObjectId)
query.getFirstObjectInBackground { (object, error) in
    if error != nil || object == nil {
       // ---- 
    } else {

        let searchKey = "File-\(PFUser.current()!.objectId!)"
        downloadedAudio.add(object?.object(forKey: "partAudio") as! PFFile, forKey: file)
        downloadedAudio.add(object?.object(forKey: "partName") as! String, forKey: searchKey)
        let downloadedFile = object?.object(forKey: "partAudio") as! PFFile
        downloadedFile.getDataInBackground({ (data, error) in
```

Comment: Is the searchKey field as a type Array in parse server? Your last line has some extra stuff around it... share your whole swift parse download code and what error does it print... in my projects it works great...

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you are getting that error because `"File-rZVgZNpNuB"` is an invalid key. Remember that keys can only start with a lowercase letter.